# Camelot: DeprecationError: PdfFileReader is deprecated

Tags: python, pypdf, python-camelot

I have been using camelot for our project, but since 2 days I got following errorMessage. When trying to run following code snippet:

```
import camelot
tables = camelot.read_pdf('C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\foo.pdf', pages='1')
```

I get this error:

```
DeprecationError: PdfFileReader is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use PdfReader instead.
```

I checked this file and it does use pdfFileReader: c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\camelot\handlers.py

I thought that I can specify the version of PyPDF2, but it will be installed automatically(because the library is used by camelot) when I install camelot. Do you think there is any solution to specify the version of PyPDF2 manually?

Comment: In the requirements of `camelot` is specified that it needs `PyPDF2>=1.26.0`. So as long as you install a version that satisfies that requirement, everything should be fine. An [issue](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/339) regarding this problem already exists on their GitHub.

Comment: you can try to manually install the package:  `pip install pypdf<3.0.0`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is [issues #339](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/339).

While there will hopefully be soon a release including the fix, you can still do this:

```
pip install 'PyPDF2<3.0'
```

after you've installed camelot.

See https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/339#issuecomment-1367331630 for details and screenshots.

Comment: I tried pip install `PyPDF2<3.0` in Colab but still received the error `DeprecationError: PdfFileReader is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use PdfReader instead`

Comment: You still have `PyPDF2>=3.0`. This error message didn't exist before 3.0.

Comment: @ChristineTan I had this same issue. Double check your PyPDF2 version (pip3 show PyPDF2), and if less than 3.0, restart your kernel/venv and rerun your code.

Comment: Issue still exists.

Comment: As [camelot is dead](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/343#issuecomment-1837270692), it will also not go away.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone trying to do this **on colab** then run the following steps:

```bash
!pip install ghostscript
!pip install camelot-py[cv]
!pip install excalibur-py
!apt install ghostscript python3-tk
```

And after that check if installed:

```py
from ctypes.util import find_library

# It will display `libgs.so.9` if installed or will print `None` if not
print(find_library("gs"))
```

If still doesn't work:

```bash
!excalibur initdb
```

---

Source: [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleColab/comments/k7lwfc/runtimeerror_please_make_sure_that_ghostscript_is/)

Answer (score 1):

```
DeprecationError: PdfFileReader is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use PdfReader instead.
```

Just removing the file from `pdfFileReader` worked for me. This means writing this **PdfReader** instead of `pdfFileReader` this.

Comment: Please explain with a block of code for easier comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the imports as the error msg suggested:

```
# From
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

# To
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
```

In my case (version `PyPDF2 3.0.0`) both classes exists.
And I thought that I need to change the code or something, but no, simply worked.

Answer (score 0):

On M2 Mac this worked -

1. `brew install ghostscript tcl-tk`
2. `pip install camelot-py[base]`
3. `pip install 'PyPDF2<3.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Okay camelot installation was a bit of pain:

Here is what is worked for me on windows 10 with python 3.11 64bit

**WHAT NOT TO DO:**

1. Do **NOT** **RUN** `pip install camelot` if you have already done it remove it by running `pip uninstall camelot` (Its a different package)
2. Do **NOT** **RUN** `pip install camelot-py` if you have already done it remove it by running `pip uninstall camelot-py` (It will  install camelot without the dependencies)
3. Do **NOT** **RUN** `pip install camelot-py[all]` if you have already done it remove it by running `pip uninstall camelot-py[all]` (It will intall the older version `camelot-py-0.9.0` which contains Depraceted code )

**WHAT TO DO:**

1. pip install camelot-py[cv2]
2. Verify installed version, should be `camelot-py-0.11.0` or newer
3. Restart python
4. Install Ghostscript (https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install-deps.html#install-deps)
5. Add the folowing paths to your PATH var:

`C:\Program Files\gs\gs{you gs ver here}\lib`

`C:\Program Files\gs\gs{you gs ver here}\bin`

6. Run `pip install ghostscript`
7. Restart python
8. `import camelot` -->Grats you are finally Done!

**Note:**
Steps 4-7 only needed if you would like to use lattice mode for stream mode you only need steps 1-3

According to the docs you might also need activetcl see (https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install-deps.html#install-deps) i have not installed it.

Comment: You also need to install opencv pip install opencv-python

Answer (score -2):

I solved the issue **uninstalling camelot-py** and re installing it includeing  the "extra cv requirement", like this:

```
pip install "camelot-py[base]"
```

I hope it can be useful!

source: https://readthedocs.org/projects/camelot-py/downloads/pdf/master/

Comment: You don't need to Uninstaller. Just upgrade with - -upgrade

Comment: There is already an answer. Check out [this](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/339)